# How to clean Vimperator search highlights

Tags: firefox, vimperator

In **Vimperator**, press <kbd>/</kbd> and do a search. If there are matches, all will be highlighted.

My question is how to clean these highlights in a decent way.

My current approach is to press <kbd>/</kbd> again, and type in a random string like "abcdefgh", enter, and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to clean the red warning in command window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:nohlsearch` command will remove the search highlights.  You could map this to a key if you use it frequently.

Answer (score 9):

Type the following to quickly clear highlighted text

> :noh

or you can toggle it highlight with

> :set hls!

Comment: I combined this with other answers by remapping it and storing it in the config file. For other newbs, here are the steps (Ubuntu): 1) `:mkv` to make the `~/.vimperatorcc` file. 2) Edit that file in editor of choice (e.g. vim or nano), adding the following: `map ? :noh<CR>`. I also added a comment above it to explain it: `" Remap ? from 'Search backwards' to 'clear find highlights'`. I chose `?` because I just don't use "search backwards". I just search and then `shift+N` to look backwards. And obviously, `?` is inverse of `/` which starts the search.

Answer (score 2):

**Remaping is awesome and you should do it!**

To add to the answers above:
You can remap some of the keys to handle this automatically for you.
e.g. put this to your `~/.vimperatorrc`

```
" adjust search to enable highlight when searching and disable when escape is pressed
noremap n :set hlsearch<return>n
noremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>
```

Explanation:
`noremap` - remaps a key sequence without remaping keys.
`n` key to remap.
`:set hlsearch<return>n` function we want remap to perform in this case enable highlighting.

This will set highlight on when you click `n` (for the next search result) and turn it off when you click escape. You can also use `/` instead of `n` if you want highlight on when you start search instantly.